# Replace parts of string that match a pattern

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to remove parts of a URL String (Protocol, query strings, etc)

For example, the following input strings

```
https://www.example.com/xyz/page.html?id=10&name=smith
http://www.example.com/abc/index.html#
https://www.example.com/abc/
www.example.com/abc
example.com/abc
http://example.com/abc
```

will become

```
example.com/xyz/page.html
example.com/abc/index.html
example.com/abc
example.com/abc
example.com/abc
example.com/abc
```

This is what I've done so far,

```
string CleanUrl(string urlString)
{
        urlString = Regex.Replace(urlString, @"^https?://", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        urlString = Regex.Replace(urlString, @"^www\.", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        urlString = Regex.Replace(urlString, @"#$", "");
        urlString = Regex.Replace(urlString, @"/$", "");
        return urlString;
}
```

I'm looking for a better way to do this, maybe with a single `Regex.Replace` or something similar

**EDIT:** Sorry, I wasn't clear with my question. My input strings sometimes do not contain the protocol and/or the `www.` part, which results in a `System.UriFormatException` When using the `Uri(urlString)` constructor. I have updated the example inputs.

Comment: Take a look at URI documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri You can actually strip the URL using this class

Comment: If your strings are all urls, you might use an alternation and remove the parts that you dont' want from the string by replacing with an empty string `^(?:https?://www\.|https?://|www\.)?|(?:[/#/]|\?.*)$` See a [demo](https://rextester.com/HALQE98816)

Comment: @cyberpirate92 Did that work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all of your strings are urls and you don't have to verify that structure, for your example data you might use an alternation to match what you want to remove from your urls and replace with an empty string.

`^(?:https?://www\.|https?://|www\.)?|(?:[#/]|\?.*)$`

**Explanation**

- `^(?:https?://www\.|https?://|www\.)?` Assert the start of the string followed by an optional non capturing group which will match either http with an optional s followed by :// www. or only the http:// part or only the www. part.
- `|` Or
- `(?:[#/]|\?.*)$` Match either one of `#/` or match a questionmark and zero or more times any character and assert the end of the string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BZKkR1/1)

[C# demo](https://rextester.com/FNKM83266)

Answer (score 1):

I would use what I commented in the question.

Code would be something like this:

```
   public string ReplaceUrl(string input)
    {
        Uri uri = new Uri(input);

        string uriWithoutQueryParams = uri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path);

        string uriWithoutSchema = uriWithoutQueryParams.Replace(uri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Scheme), string.Empty);

        string uriWithoutTripleW = uriWithoutSchema.Replace("www.", string.Empty);

        string uriWithoutTrailingSlash = uriWithoutTripleW.TrimEnd(new char[] {'/' });

        return uriWithoutTrailingSlash;
    }
```

Here's the test method should you want it as well (using XUnit)

```
    [Theory]
    [InlineData("https://www.example.com/xyz/page.html?id=10&name=smith", "example.com/xyz/page.html")]
    [InlineData("http://www.example.com/abc/index.html#", "example.com/abc/index.html")]
    [InlineData("https://www.example.com/abc/", "example.com/abc")]
    public void MyUrlConverterReplacesCorrectly(string inputUrl, string expectedUrl)
    {
        string actualUrl = MyUrlConverter.ReplaceUrl(inputUrl);

        Assert.Equal(expectedUrl, actualUrl);
    }
```

Comment: Sorry I couldn't find a more standard way to remove the trailing `/` or the `www.` (which is something you wouldn't expect to do anyhow) but there's nothing in the `Uri` docs on how to handle this. If it were MVC you could prevent any URI from having trailing slashes :)

Also, the method name is not one of my best... But giving answers quickly is very priced here so I had to somewhat hurry

Answer (score 0):

Don't use RegEx for this. Instead, use the `Uri` class to parse the URL string and then use the `Host` and `AbsolutePath` properties to get your final string:

```
var uri = new Uri("https://www.example.com/xyz/page.html?id=10&name=smith");
var result = uri.Host + uri.AbsolutePath;
if (result.EndsWith("/"))
    result = result.Remove(result.Length - 1, 1);
if (result.StartsWith("www."))
    result = result.Substring(4);
```

Comment: With `Host` you still get the `www`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        static string CleanUrl(string urlString)
        {
            urlString = Regex.Replace(urlString, @"\s+", "");
            urlString = Regex.Replace(urlString, @"^https?://", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            urlString = Regex.Replace(urlString, @"^www\.", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            urlString = Regex.Replace(urlString, @"(#|\?).*$", "");
            urlString = Regex.Replace(urlString, @"/$", "");
            return urlString;
        }
```